# KeyError: "text" when preprocessing for tokenizing

Tags: text, twitter, tokenize, keyerror

I am trying to tokenize .json files of tweets with this code:

```
*from nltk.corpus import brown
brown.words()
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import json
import re
```

. 
.
.
    **with open('volby2018_1.json', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            tweet = json.loads(line)
            tokens = preprocess(tweet['text'])***

and I am constantly getting:

```
    **KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-2-daba85c11858> in <module>()
         52     for line in f:
         53         tweet = json.loads(line)
--->     54         tokens = preprocess(tweet['text'])
         55 
         56 print(preprocess(tweet))
    KeyError: 'text'**
```

.json looks like this:

> *{"statuses":[{"created_at":"Sun Feb 04 09:26:24 +0000
>   2018","id":960082100341919744,"id_str":"960082100341919744","text":"@PREZIDENTmluvci
>   Voli\u010d\u016fm Zemana. Sd\u00edlejte. #Zeman v debate na TV den
>   p\u0159ed #Volby2018 potvrdil, \u017ee je\u2026
>   https://t.co/bZOlX2DjqK","truncated":true,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"Zeman","indices":[43,49]},{"text":"Volby2018","indices":[74,84]}],"symbols":[],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"PREZIDENTmluvci","name":"Ji\u0159\u00ed
>   Ov\u010d\u00e1\u010dek","id":3055366126,"id_str":"3055366126","indices":[0,16]}],"urls":[{"url":"https://t.co/bZOlX2DjqK","expanded_url":"https://twitter.com/i/web/status/960082100341919744","display_url":"twitter.com/i/web/status/9\u2026","indices":[102,125]}]},"metadata":{"iso_language_code":"cs","result_type":"recent"},"source":"\u003ca
>   href=\"http://twitter.com/download/android\"
>   rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for
>   Android\u003c/a\u003e","in_reply_to_status_id":960080132764467200,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":"960080132764467200","in_reply_to_user_id":3055366126,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":"3055366126","in_reply_to_screen_name":"PREZIDENTmluvci","user":{"id":1915891352,"id_str":"1915891352","name":"Zden\u011bk
>   Bub\u00e1k","screen_name":"ZdenekBubak","location":"\u0160\u00e9fredaktor
>   / Editor in Chief","description":"Redaktor se specializac\u00ed na
>   finan\u010dn\u00ed
>   produkty","url":"https://t.co/nvivnZXApP","entities":{"url":{"urls":[{"url":"https://t.co/nvivnZXApP","expanded_url":"http://www.finparada.cz","display_url":"finparada.cz","indices":[0,23]}]},"description":{"urls":[]}},"protected":false,"followers_count":196,"friends_count":201,"listed_count":3,"created_at":"Sun
>   Sep 29 02:09:56 +0000
>   2013","favourites_count":782,"utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":true,"verified":false,"statuses_count":4821,"lang":"cs","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"is_translation_enabled":false,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","profile_background_image_url":"http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_image_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/843934466175356928/94cCpcLK_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/843934466175356928/94cCpcLK_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/1915891352/1380992989","profile_link_color":"1DA1F2","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"has_extended_profile":false,"default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":false,"following":false,"follow_request_sent":false,"notifications":false,"translator_type":"none"},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":{"id":"018e2bf71a3ef896","url":"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/id/018e2bf71a3ef896.json","place_type":"city","name":"Prague","full_name":"Prague,
>   Czech Republic","country_code":"CZ","country":"Czech
>   Republic","contained_within":[],"bounding_box":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[14.2252428,49.9419037],[14.7065078,49.9419037],[14.7065078,50.1772562],[14.2252428,50.1772562]]]},"attributes":
>   * ....